# Lambda function with two input parameter in linq Select clause

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How does the following code works?

```
int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
array.Select((a,b) => (a,b))
```

Comment: Reading [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) can be useful

Comment: @jira While I agree, someone new to the language may be easily confused by the combination of the 2-arg lambda and the 2-arg tuple creation which look quite similar, especially when the lambda is a single expression and lacks the return keyword. I took this less to be about Select and more about Tuples. You and I know, but what does a beginner search for? "two variables in parentheses followed by two variables in parentheses" doesn't get much of a Google hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) where the lambda passed to it accepts two parameters. The first is the item in the collection and the second is its zero-based index.

Your example is projecting every item in the source array to a two-item `ValueTuple<int, int>` where the individual components represent the original source item and it's position/index within the collection. The syntax for a two item `ValueTuple` is `(value1, value2)` -- but don't confuse this with the syntax for a two-argument lambda which is *similarly* `(arg1, arg2) =>`.

If it helps visualize it better, that line can be rewritten as the following:

```
array.Select((val, index) => { 
    return new ValueTuple<int, int>(val, index);
});
```

Note though that `Select` on its own doesn't really do anything. You need to materialize it with a call to `ToList`/`ToArray` or to `foreach` over the collection (usually after assigning to a variable) for it to really *mean* anything. The tuple components can than be accessed using the `Item1` and `Item2` properties:

```
var items = array.Select((val, index) => (val, index));
foreach (var item in items) 
   Console.WriteLine($"The value at position {item.Item2} is {item.Item1}");
```

Or they can be accessed via [*deconstruction*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#deconstruction) into seperate variables:

```
foreach (var (value, index) in items) 
   Console.WriteLine($"The value at position {index} is {value}");
```

Alternatively, you can provide tuple element names at the time of tuple creation. Those names can then be used (thanks to some compiler magic) in place of `ItemN`:

```
var items = array.Select((val, index) => (Value: val, Pos: index));
foreach (var item in items) 
   Console.WriteLine($"The value at position {item.Pos} is {item.Value}");
```

Answer (score 1):

It gets every element of an array and its index and maps it to [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2?view=netcore-3.1) using overload of [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) method, which accepts element and index. Then the result should be assigned to a variable (this part is missing in your code)

```cs
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var result = array.Select((a, b) => (a, b));
```

The result type is `IEnumerable<(int, int)>`, I guess you should materialize to list or an array

```cs
var result = array.Select((a, b) => (a, b)).ToList();
```

Items are accessible using `Item1` and `Item2` properties or your own names, if you'll give them when call `Select`

```cs
var result = array.Select((a, b) => (Item: a, Index: b)).ToList();
var item = result[0].Item;
var index = result[0].Index;
```